# Select equal number of records for the WHERE conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a database and over one million records in it. I want to get the same number of records from the database for 3 different conditions. I am currently using code that performs 3 MySQL queries. I wonder if there is a possibility to get the same result using one SELECT query?.

The following code select an equal number of 20 records for each site=X condition.

```
<?php
/*---------*/
$db1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM news WHERE site='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,20");

$db2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM news WHERE site='2' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,20");

$db3 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM news WHERE site='3' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,20");

/*------------*/

?>
```

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? There is one more way possible depending on the server version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`UNION ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to combine results of multiple Select queries. We need to ensure that the number of columns being returned are same in all the Select queries.

```
(SELECT * FROM news WHERE site='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,20)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM news WHERE site='2' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,20)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM news WHERE site='3' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,20)
```

Now, always remember that the result of the UNION will always be an Unordered dataset. In case, you intend the final results to be sorted by `id`; you can add an explicit `Order By` at the end. It is very well discussed in the [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html):

> However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies
>   nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result
>   because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore,
>   the use of ORDER BY in this context is typically in conjunction with
>   LIMIT, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows
>   to retrieve for the SELECT, even though it does not necessarily affect
>   the order of those rows in the final UNION result. If ORDER BY appears
>   without LIMIT in a SELECT, it is optimized away because it will have
>   no effect anyway.